# displaying Array info from My SQL

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i have tryed many ways to get this to work am unsure where my error is. i get the Error message.

```
mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in
```

This is the Code:

```
$dbh = mysqli_connect("HOST", $user_name, $password, $database_name);
if (!$dbh)
{
    die("Not connected : " . mysqli_error($dbh));
}

if ($method=="graces")
{ 
   $query = "SELECT id, name FROM raceslog";
    $userinfo = array();

      while ($row_user = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
       $userinfo[] = $row_user;}

       foreach ($userinfo as $user) {
         echo "^{$user[id]}"
            . "^{$user[name]}";
        }
 }
```

Well my question is does anyone see where my error is and could point me in the right direction to fix Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually run the query first with `mysqli_query`.  Also note that `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` are not compatible.  You should stick with mysqli and properly parameterize your queries.

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbh, $query);
while ($row_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```

You can also echo in the `while` loop if you want.